# Sufficient conditions for Implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I need to determine whether the surface whose equation is $xy - y (logz) +sin(xz) = 0 $ can be represented in the form $z= f(x,y)$ near $(0,2,1)$ using implicit function theorem. Assume $f$ to be a smooth function.

If I apply Implicit function theorem here and calculate the $M(x,y,z)$ matrix formed by differentiating the function $xy - y (logz) +sin(xz) = f(x,y,z)$ with respect to $z$ then at $(0,2,1)$, I am getting this matrix to be invertible. Is this sufficient to show the required condition?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see (from Wikipedia):

> Let $f: \Bbb R^{n+m} → \Bbb R^m$ be a continuously differentiable function, and let $\Bbb R^{n+m}$ have coordinates $(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)$. Fix a point $(\mathbf a, \mathbf b) = (a_1, ..., a_n, b_1, ..., b_m)$ with $f(\mathbf a, \mathbf b) = \mathbf c$, where $\mathbf c \in \Bbb R^m$. If the matrix $\left [\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j}(a, b)\right ]$ is invertible, then there exists an open set $U$ containing $\mathbf a$, an open set $V$ containing $\mathbf b$, and a unique continuously differentiable function $g: U \to V$ such that
>   $$\{ (\mathbf{x}, g(\mathbf{x}))|\mathbf x \in U \} = \{ (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) \in U \times V| f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{c} \}.$$

$f$ is continuously differentiable? Yes.
Derivative matrix of $f$ is invertible? Yes.

Looks like you're covered.

Comment: Ok. But what if the matrix isn't invertible. Then how can we determined if xy−y(logz)+sin(xz)=0 can be represented in the form z=f(x,y) near (0,2,1)

Comment: In that case, you will have to turn to other techniques. Most likely there is no implicit function at this point. But it is possible that the function has the multi-dimensional equivalent to an inflection point there and an implicit function does exist. But there is no handy fallback technique when the implicit function theorem fails. You have to figure it out based on the function.